# Improve performance of index reorganize on volatile table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ola-hallengren, index-maintenance

This is occurring on SQL Server 2016 (Enterprise).
Example Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Foo](
    [FooId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstFkId] [bigint] NULL,
    [SecondFkId] [bigint] NULL,
    [ThirdFkId] [bigint] NULL,
    [FourthFkId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [ParentId] [bigint] NULL,
    [Flag1] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Flag2] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [From] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [Until] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [ChangedBy] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ChangedOn] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Foo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [FooId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FooDetail](
    [FooDetailId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FooId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [FirstFkId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [SecondFkId] [bigint] NULL,
    [Column1] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Column2] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [Column3] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [Column4] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [Column5] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [Column6] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [Column7] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [Column8] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [ChangedBy] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ChangedOn] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_FooDetail] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [FooDetailId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FooDetail]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_FooDetail_Foo] FOREIGN KEY([FooId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Foo] ([FooId])
```

This tables have data from a sliding window. There is a process that insert into the tables for a month every day and a different process that deletes older data. Users can insert/update rows.

Both tables have around 125.000 rows.

The data is read like this:

```
SELECT -- columns
FROM Foo f
INNER JOIN FooDetail fd on fd.FooId = f.FooId
WHERE f. -- Some condition
```

When investigating we found that the index reorganise for the clustered index of `FooDetail` takes between 90 minutes and 120 minutes. With the following command:

```
ALTER INDEX [PK_FooDetail] ON [DbName].[dbo].[FooDetail] REORGANIZE WITH (LOB_COMPACTION = ON)
```

Extend event info:

```
<ExtendedInfo>
  <PageCount>3739</PageCount>
  <Fragmentation>5.00134</Fragmentation>
</ExtendedInfo>
```

We use ola hallengren solution for index optimize (Default settings). With the following command:

```
sqlcmd -E -S $(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(SRVR)) -d master -Q "EXECUTE [dbo].[IndexOptimize] @Databases = 'USER_DATABASES', @LogToTable = 'Y'" -b
```

**Timings**

| Time | What |
| --- | --- |
| 01:30 - 01:30 | Deletes happen on the table |
| 01:35 - 05:00 | Process starts with inserts / updates |
| 02:00 - 05:30 | Reporting process is started to generate huge number of reports |
| 04:00 - xxxx | Index maintenance is started |
| 05:30 - xxxx | Integrity check => Full backup |
| Every hour | log backup |

*The reporting db and reporting tempdb have around 200 user connections open from start to finish. They generate reports that are used through the day and they put a heavy load on the system.  Creating the reports on the fly is not an option. They have to be available. Like in many cases 24 hours in a day is to short, to give every process its own time window.*

Disk speed (ms) data file:

- Avg Read Stall: 6
- Avg Write Stall: 33

Disk speed (ms) log file:

- Avg Read Stall: 5
- Avg Write Stall: 6

My question how can we speed up the index rebuild, how can we get the best improvement?

Some ideas:

- Should we exclude the table from the general index rebuild and have a seperate job to rebuild the index of these tables when we know there is less write usage? To suffer less from locking. (The application is used 24/7 so locking will always be an issue.)
- Is it a good idea, to remove the clustered index and use a heap instead, since the data is so volatile?
  (We have a different index on `FooDetail` for `FooId`)

Comment: You don't rebuild the index, you *REORGANIZE* it. Reorganizing and rebuilding are different tasks. Your table is fairly small and you are on the Enterprise edition so you could use a rebuilding command (not reorganize) with `online = on` option.

Comment: Are you using the default settings of Ola's scripts? Or have you implemented your own fragmentation trigger levels? Could you please post the job step details of your Ola Job for  the `IndexOptimize - USER_DATABASES` job? At what time of the day are you inserting the data and at what time of the day are you deleting the data? When does your `IndexOptimize` job kick in? Are you using the Enterprise Edition of SQL Server? Hit [edit] and add the details to your post. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnK.N. Updated the question. It's enterprise, stated at the top.

Answer (score 4):

There is something which is incredibly wrong here. Your tables are tiny!

Just for comparison, I did a reorg on a clustered table with 450,000 rows and 22,000 pages having 42% fragmentation level. It took 1 second. This was on my 3 years old laptop.

You need to do some troubleshooting here.

I would restore the database from a backup taken before such reorg to a new machine and do a reorg on that machine. Depending on that outcome, you will dig deeper.

If it is slow also on that machine, then there is something special about this table. Perhaps you have LOB pages, even though your post suggests you don't? I can't say why a reorg should take that long on a silent machine, but you want to have this as a baseline.

Assming the reorg is quick on the restored copy, you need to determine why it is so ultra-slow on the prod machine. Is it during that time-period? Perhaps you have blocking going on? What else is running that that time? You can for instance poll wait stats using any of the DMVs available (sys.dm_exec_session_wait_stats or sys.dm_os_wait_stats, depending on which is more convenient for you). Or just execute the reorg manually during a period where you know there isn't tons of work going on.

Rebuild is an option, of course. Or not doing defrag in the first place (perhaps you don't really gain anything from a defrag).

But considering that you have determined something way out of the ordinary, you want to get to the root of this before considering skipping defrag or doing rebuild instead.

Comment: Agreed, this table is tiny, we have different tables on the same server with millions of records, that rebuild/reorganize in <1 minute. We know for sure locking/blocking is occuring, since the table is under heavy use in the maintenance window. There are lobs on the server, but in a different database. We'll add a seperate reorganize for that table on a different time window to see if it's faster. Running it on a silent restored backup <1s.

Comment: Cool. You seem to have your actionplan. Just one note: You can exclude just this table from the regorg job using a - param to IndexOptimize. And then just stich in a rebuild using online for this table immediately after. Or, consider doing rebuilds for all instead of reorg/rebuild.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative solution would be to stop worrying about index fragmentation.  In my company, we were having similar issues with index rebuilds blocking and generally being resource-intensive on a large ERP database and another large data warehouse database in SQL Server 2016 Enterprise.  We have since stopped index rebuilds and reorganizes completely and instead update statistics daily.  There was no noticeable drop in performance.

I think the drawback to this approach is it takes more storage, but we were willing to tradeoff for better performance in this case.

Some of the larger tables in these databases have 100-200 million rows and there has not been any issue with query performance even with the clustered index being 60% fragmented.

Microsoft's guidance on index reorganize and rebuild supports this:

> For example, if a given index is used mainly for scan operations, removing fragmentation can improve performance of these operations. **The performance benefit may not be noticeable for indexes that are used primarily for seek operations**.
> Similarly, removing fragmentation in a heap (a table with no clustered index) is especially useful for nonclustered index scan operations, but has little effect in lookup operations.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/reorganize-and-rebuild-indexes?view=sql-server-2016#detecting-fragmentation-of-rowstore-indexes

If you must rebuild, since you said you have Enterprise edition, you can do online index rebuilds which should help reduce the blocking.
`REBUILD WITH (ONLINE = ON)`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/perform-index-operations-online?view=sql-server-2016